# Crear función que calcule el promedio de sumar el primero y el último elemento de una lista

Tags: haskell

Ejemplo

```
lista :[2,3,4,5,6]
```

Se toma el primer elemento de la lista, que es el `2`, y el último, que es `6`. Entonces se suman `2 + 6 = 8` y se divide entre `2` asi `2 + 6 = 8 / 2`.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te aconsejo que intentes ser más explícito en la pregunta que estás haciendo. El título debe ser lo más conciso posible y exponer en el texto de la pregunta lo que necesitas y qué has probado. El código que has puesto no parece tener relación con el título. ¿Dónde está la lista de números?¿O cuando dices lista te estás refiriendo a los dígitos de un número? No sé, no parece nada claro. Por favor, reescribe la pregunta para que quede clara y te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: corregi la pregunta me confundi ...

Comment: Me puedes ayudar

Answer (score 1):

No indicas ninguna limitación a la hora de resolver el problema, por lo que voy a poner algunas variantes.

La más sencilla es usar los métodos `head` y `last` para obtener el primero y el último elemento de la lista:

```hs
promedio :: [Integer] -> Integer
promedio xs = (head xs + last xs) `div` 2
```

Así, sin más, funciona con el ejemplo que has dado. Pero tiene dos problemas:

#### 1. Da error si la lista tiene menos de dos elementos

Para evitar que dé error podemos comprobar si la lista tiene al menos dos elementos, y dar un valor nulo en caso contrario:

```hs
promedio :: [Integer] -> Integer
promedio xs | length xs < 2 = 0
            | otherwise     = (head xs + last xs) `div` 2
```

No es una solución elegante ya que no distingue entre una lista con pocos elementos y otra lista que tenga, efectivamente, un promedio nulo.

En haskell se prefiere usar el tipo `Maybe` para resultados de funciones que puedan no dar un resultado concreto:

```hs
promedio :: [Integer] -> Maybe Integer
promedio xs | length xs < 2 = Nothing
            | otherwise     = Just $ (head xs + last xs) `div` 2
```

#### 2. No se obtiene un promedio con decimales

En haskell, una división de enteros no da resultados con decimales. En general, las operaciones en haskell son *internas*, lo que quiere decir que si divides dos enteros, tendrás como resultado un entero. Se necesitar convertir el número entero en algún tipo de dato compatible con la división de número reales. O sea, convertir el tipo `Integer` en `Integral`, algo así:

```hs
promedio :: [Integer] -> Maybe Double
promedio xs | length xs < 2 = Nothing
            | otherwise     = Just $ fromIntegral suma / 2
  where suma = head xs + last xs
```